# Create a docker container from an angular project

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, dockerfile

I want to create a docker container based on my angular project.
This is my dockerfile:

```
# here we dockerize angular app
FROM node:12-alpine3.11

WORKDIR /usr/local/lib


COPY .  /usr/local/lib/

RUN npm install

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 4200
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

The dockerfile is located in the directory of my angular project containing all of the files except for node_modules.
When i try to build my docker image i reach the build stage and get this error:
"./node_modules/primeng/fesm2015/primeng-chart.js:4:0-34 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'chart.js/auto' in '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/primeng/fesm2015'"

this is my package.json

```
{
 "name": "acm_jenkins_web",
 "version": "0.0.0",
 "scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve",
"build": "ng build",
"watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
"test": "ng test",
"sonar-scanner": "sonar-scanner"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^12.2.2",
"@angular/cdk": "^12.2.2",
"@angular/common": "~12.0.3",
"@angular/compiler": "~12.0.3",
"@angular/core": "~12.0.3",
"@angular/forms": "~12.0.3",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~12.0.3",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.0.3",
"@angular/router": "~12.0.3",
"@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
"bootstrap": "^3.0.0",
"chart.js": "^2.9.4",
"jquery": "^3.6.0",
"ngx-toastr": "^14.0.0",
"popper.js": "^1.16.1",
"primeicons": "^4.1.0",
"primeng": "^12.0.0-rc.1",
"rxjs": "~6.6.0",
"tslib": "^2.1.0",
"zone.js": "~0.11.4"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.0.3",
"@angular/cli": "~12.0.3",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.0.3",
"@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
"@types/node": "^12.11.1",
"jasmine-core": "~3.7.0",
"karma": "~6.3.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
"karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
"karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
"typescript": "~4.2.3",
"sonar-scanner": "^3.1.0"
 }
 }
```

Comment: I presume this is SSR app, correct?

Comment: not familiar with the term

Answer (score 0):

Did you try such steps on local machine (not docker)?

- delete local `node_modules` folder completely
- use `npm i` to install deps
- run `npm build` on the local machine

In case you get the same issue, the reason can be installing incorrect version of this two packages and you can dig this way:

```
"chart.js": "^2.9.4",
...
"primeng": "^12.0.0-rc.1",
```

Othervise you can save `package-lock.json` after steps above and try to run `npm ci` command instead of `npm install`.

It should help if there's sth incorrect with deps

Comment: Small comment: be careful as when you run `npm build` on local machine, the folder `dist` will be created which should be copied to docker container with the command `
COPY .  /usr/local/lib/`. It's redundant so you should prevent the copying.

Comment: i did all of the above but still get the chart.js error

Comment: @YoussefBoudaya did you get the same error while you run `npm build` directly in your computer without building docker image?

Comment: you mean ng build ? yes

Comment: Then you can try suggestions from here as there's no issue with docker:
https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/7887